# (JavaScript+Java+Rest) application design approach

Tags: design-patterns, application-design, web-application-design

I am working with a new framework called "Play! Framework" which follows MVC pattern.

My web application has java model and controller classes and (html+javascript) at view layer.

Also we don't have our own database...application data comes through a rest based web service (on demand) based on which TAB/MENU user has clicked.

My questions are-

1) I am right now calling various java controllers right from the various .html files using (jquery+play)syntax...is this a good approach ?

2)At server side we have multiple REST services to fetch different type of data. I have right now used "DAO" to configure and hit REST web services and "DTO" for modelling model objects(these objects will carry data fetched by REST) and render them in JQuery DataTable respectively....Is this alright ?

3)REST returns us JSON data on which we have to do some processing in order to make them suitable for showing into JQuery DataTable...right now this logic is written into Java Helper classes for each functionality of my web application...is this OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks Good 
you are in the right way 
i am using same mechanism

but when your using javascript than all you **Rest URI is exposed to end user** so need to think about Security.

[image]

Comment: sorry for late reply but this application will be accessible only after proper authentication which is based on ADS based security system. Also, it's not going to be run into public network...do you still feel that exposing REST URI to javascript will be a security threat?

Comment: no dear
you can run this in public but you need to change some feature
i am using this system for public and use security mechanism developed by me.